# Mic volume automatically changed to default

Tags: 20.10

The mic volume automatically changed to default and it can not be muted. The OS is Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: Click "edit" just below the text of your question, and correct the misspelling of "song". Also, include your Ubuntu version in the text of your question. Then you can delete your comment.

Comment: What kind of sound do the participants hear?

Comment: I do not know what kind of sound they can hear; only they can hear

Comment: What meeting platform are you using?

Comment: If you go to Settings | Sound, under the Input section, what happens when you slide the volume control to the right? While *not* in a meeting, does the slider stay there, or does it slide to the left, automatically? If you do the same while *in* a meeting, does the slider stay there, or does it slide to the left, automatically?

Comment: It slides to the left when I am both in and not in a meeting.

Comment: I think you have a sticky key... It may be the lower-volume key. If you have a keyboard that you can disconnect, try disconnecting it and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: I do not have a sticky key problem @PJSingh